# Install Sw in /usr/local but bash terminal doesn't see programs

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, netbeans

I'm a newbie Ubuntu 14.04 User. I need Netbeans to develop software so I decided to install the 8.0.1 version. Since the pkg installer doesn't have the latest version, I downloaded the `.sh` file from the Official Site. Thus I install it in a very simple way, putting it in `/usr/local` directory as well.
Now there is a problem, typing "`netbeans`" in bash doesn't work and it says:

```
The program 'netbeans' is currently not installed. 
You can install it by typing:
```

`sudo apt-get install netbeans`

Of course, with the suggested command I will install the old version of the program, instead of the `8.0.1` one. 
Despite that, typing "`netbeans`" in the ubuntu search bar works without mistakes.

How can fix this problem? Should I install the program in another directory?
Thanks for your kindness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/usr/local/` itself isn't in the default path, `/usr/local/bin` is.

Move your launch script there and it should be picked up.

---

In your case, you're installing the entire thing into `/usr/local/netbeans-<VERSION>/`. This includes a launcher script in `./bin/netbeans`. The simple fix for you is to just symlink to that launcher from somewhere in the path:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/netbeans-8.0.1/bin/netbeans /usr/local/bin/
```

Then `netbeans` will launch that script. You'll need to update the symlink when you upgrade Netbeans.

Comment: So, now do I have to to uninstall and then specify the path /usr/local/bin ? Is this the way to install all the pkg with this extension (.sh) ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Andrea I had a play around with the actual installer and you can leave things where they are and just create a symlink. I've added code that works for the version I downloaded and installed.

Answer (score 2):

The script that you dropped into /usr/local is not a usable netbeans application but rather an install script for it. Move it back into your home directory somewhere and following the installation instructions found here:

[Netbeans IDE - Installation Instructions](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/80/install.html)

Comment: Already done it. My netbeans-8.0.1-cpp-linux.sh was in /home/downloads folder. Then following the instructions, I installed it but specifying the folder /usr/local.